# How can I use vectorization/loop to create a multi-level pivot with second level filtered on 'top 5' values for each level?

Tags: python-3.x

My data set looks like this with I,A,B,C,D,E as columns

```
 I    A              B               C                   D           E          F    
[IDs][5 diff values][45 diff values][34 different dates][24 diff col][101branches][values]
```

I want to make a pivot with

```
index = [C,E,B(subset),A]
columns = [D]
values = [F]
function = sum
```

PROBLEM- I want to create a filter so that in my index [C,B(subset),E], the 'B' values are only 5 instead of all the 45 values in my data set.
This filter would be of the form

```
pseudo code:

For each month in 'C'
pick out top 5 'B' for which sum of 'F'is highest
```

So, for each month in C, we include only those 5 B i.e. B(subset) in our pivot.

I have created a dictionary with the B(subset) for each month stored.
How to encorporate it into the pivot? Tried flagging each entry individually with 'B.value'='B.value'if in top 5 in C, or else 'B.value' = 'OTHERS'if not in top 5 and running pivot on this flagged column.

PROBLEM - Have around 20,00,000 rows which is taking enormous amount of time.

Comment: Reformatted code

Comment: How do values in B and E relate? How is "the sum of E" computed? Your first step is entirely reasonable.

Comment: I have updated it. B is a business and F(earlier E) is expense in that business. So for every month in 'C', I want the B's with highest expense in every E(branch). So my filter looks like 5 B's for every combination of [E,B,C](branch, business month). And these top five business I want to feed in my final pivot.